# drupal 7 user registration custom url returning a blank page

Tags: users, routes

I dont think my url is working. I am trying to use page/medical then use the page callback to redirect to medical_reg_form_user_register_form_alter. Instead of displaying the form I get a blank page.

```
function medical_reg_user_register_menu() {
  $items['page/medical'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'medical_reg_form_user_register_form_alter',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
    );
  return $items;
}

function medical_reg_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#theme'] = 'medical_register'; 
  $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Nextdfd');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't call a hook in `hook_menu()`. You can either create an alias for the user registration page or replace your menu item with:

```
function medical_reg_user_register_menu() {
  $items['page/medical'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('user_register_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
    );
  return $items;
}
```

Comment: This is correct: Using a hook also as page callback is fount of troubles. The least it can happen is that the arguments the function gets as page callback are not the same it would get as hook implementation. In this case, as page callback, the function would not get any argument, while the hook is expecting 3 parameters.